# Robot Framework: Way to include pipe (|) characters in actual variables and not as a separator?

Tags: robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework via text format with a .robot file setup.  I have been looking for a way to include a pipe character `|` with a space on each side in the variable to be readable content in the variable, without it causing Robot Framework to treat it as a separator.  The problem is that Robot Framework always treats a pipe character with at least one space on each side of it as a separator in text format.

The reason I am looking for this is because in my tests, using Selenium2Library, some page titles I am linking to have pipe characters in them with spaces that I need to verify, preferably with an exact text match.

My variable in Robot Framework looks like this:

```
| ${MY VARIABLE} | This site | Check it out |
```

In python, this would look like this:

```
MY_VARIABLE = "This site | Check it out"
```

The above variable should include the pipe character, but in the Robot Framework example, the middle pipe character acts as a separator in the variable (since it has a space on each side of it just like the other pipe character separators).

Is there a way to tell Robot Framework to include this " | " in the content, such as wrapping the content of the variable somehow?  I've tried using brackets, parenthesis and curly braces, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prefix the pipe with a backslash. The [robot framework users guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html) has a section on [escaping](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escaping):

> There is no need to escape empty cells (other than the trailing empty
>   cells) when using the pipe and space separated format. The only thing
>   to take into account is that possible pipes surrounded by spaces in
>   the actual test data must be escaped with a backslash

Here's an example:

```
*** Variables ***
| ${MY VARIABLE} | THis site \| Check it out

*** Test Cases ***
| Example #1
| | log to console | ${MY VARIABLE}
```