# expected 2 keywords got 4 in robot framework

Tags: docker, kubernetes, automated-tests, robotframework

How can this problem be solved for example,  The Execute special command on accepts 2 arguments, but I want to make it accept more. I want these two commands to be together so that I can replace the yaml file of a docker image at once. I have tried putting the other commands in brackets but it didnt still work

```
Execute special command on     ${cluster}        kubectl exec -n ${namespace} get statefulsets/postgresql-pod -o yaml | sed "s#image: docker repo /stolon#image: bbbdocker repo/stolon#"
```

```
Execute special command on     ${cluster}        kubectl -n ${namespace} replace -f -
```

Comment: You may have to escape pipe character, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831621/robot-framework-way-to-include-pipe-characters-in-actual-variables-and-not

Comment: @pekka I am getting error as a result. The result is Error
```Execute special command on     ${cluster}        kubectl exec -n ${namespace} get statefulsets/postgresql-pod -o yaml \| sed "s#image: docker repo /stolon#image: bbbdocker repo/stolon#"|\Execute special command on     ${cluster}        kubectl -n ${namespace} replace -f -
```

Comment: Your comment does not show full error message, can you append it to your question. Before you do that, you have two pipe characters and you have escaped only one. Make sure you escape both.

Comment: ``` 
${corrupt_image}= Execute special command on ${cluster} kubectl exec -n ${namespace} get statefulsets/postgresql-pod -o yaml \| sed "s#image: docker repo /stolon#image: bbbdocker repo/stolon#"\|Execute special command on ${cluster} kubectl -n ${namespace} replace -f - ``` 
the result shows this. it passes the execution but returns this as a value ${corrupt_image}== ERROR –

Comment: @pekka? what do you think

Comment: Your last comment does not show input or output correctly. Please add your latest RF command and its error message to your question.

Comment: hello, please share the status of your issue based on the above comments. If resolved please post the answer so, that it will be beneficial for other community members.